# Is there a feat like Flick of the Wrist for thrown weapons that does not involve feinting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, throwing-things

Is there a feat like [Flick of the Wrist](http://dnd.arkalseif.info/feats/races-of-the-wild--84/flick-of-the-wrist--1144/index.html) for thrown weapons that does not involve feinting?

> **Benefit**: If you draw a light weapon and make a melee attack with it in the same round, you catch your opponent flat-footed (for the purpose of this attack only). You can use this feat only once per round and once per opponent during any single combat encounter.

Comment: @HeyICanChan probably meant. "Can you link to a feat that is similar to what you want in pathfinder?"

Comment: You dont want it to involve feinting because of the bluff skill? Because there are ways to make feint checks with other skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any that would provide this to you automatically as Flick of the Wrist does. The closest I've found is [False Opening (Ultimate Combat)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/false-opening-combat/), which can grant you ranged attacks that deny the target its dexterity bonus to AC, but it's both expensive and situational. For rogues, the rogue talents [Snap Shot (Advanced Player's Guide)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/snap-shot-ex/) and [Surprise Attack (Core Rulebook)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/surprise-attack-ex/) can also be used, but these only work during the surprise round.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sniping](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth) for hitting flat-footed from range, without using feint.

> If you’ve already successfully used Stealth at least 10 feet from your target, you can make one ranged attack and then immediately use Stealth again. You take a –20 penalty on your Stealth check to maintain your obscured location.

This penalty to maintaining the stealth can be reduced by taking [Expert Sniper](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/expert-sniper-combat/), and eventually you can snipe twice in a turn using [Master Sniper](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/master-sniper-combat/).

Alternatively, if you can make an enemy shaken as a free or swift action somehow, you could use [Shatter Defenses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shatter-defenses-combat), to make them flat-footed to you.

> Any shaken, frightened, or panicked opponent hit by you this round is flat-footed to your attacks until the end of your next turn. This includes any additional attacks you make this round.